# php regex find matches

Tags: php, regex

I've got the following code:

```
if (preg_match('/fl=(.*)&/', $resp, $matches)) {
    $temp=$matches[0];
    $fl= str_replace("fl=", '',$temp);
   }
```

I want to get the text from  `$resp` that is after `fl=` and before the next `&`

The problem I am having is that it ignores the first few `&'s`. 
The output I'm currently getting is `Email&errorType=format&"` what i want is `Email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use lazy matching `.*?` or negated character class `[^&]*`.

```
$resp = "/fl=123&gh=word&more=params";
if (preg_match('/fl=(.*?)&/', $resp, $matches)) {
    $fl=$matches[1];
    echo $fl;
   }
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/uDXC6N)

Note that `.*` is too *greedy*, meaning that it matches as many characters to the right of the string as possible. It happens so because the regex engine grabs the whole substring up to the last `&` and then backtracks to find that it can actually capture that whole substring. With `.*?`, we get the closest next `&`.